# How do default values of Class fields work in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I saw this piece of code in MDN while I was learning some syntax about Class in JavaScript today, which really confused me. [Here it is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#field_declarations:%7E:text=class%20Rectangle%20%7B%0A%20%20height%20%3D%200%3B%0A%20%20width%3B%0A%20%20constructor(height%2C%20width)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.height%20%3D%20height%3B%0A%20%20%20%20this.width%20%3D%20width%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D):

```js
class Rectangle {
  height = 0;
  width;
  constructor(height, width) {
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }
}
```

If I create an instance of Rectangle without passing into any arguments, the default value of height 0 doesn't work on the instance.

```js
const rec = new Rectangle();
//  { height: undefined, width: undefined }
```

My question is "Is this piece of code is a bad practice?". If a class filed has been assigned inside the constructor, we shouldn't give a default value to the class outside the constructor because it will always not work. Instead, we can set a default of a class field that hasn't been assigned inside the constructor like below:

```js
class Rectangle {
  height = 10;
  width;
  constructor(width) {
    this.width = width;
  }
}

const rec = new Rectangle();

console.log(rec);
// { height: 10, width: undefined }
```

The default value works in this case.

Comment: `constructor(height = 0, width)`

Comment: Is that a bad code?

Comment: what I wrote? I **never** write bad code :D - oh, you WILL want `this.height = height` inside constructor of course

Comment: If I want the `this.height = height` inside constructor, the default value seems to be useless, isn't it?

Comment: I think you can see that in your code, isn't it?

Comment: well, yes, it's clearly meaningless - sorry, didn't realise what the question was

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide arguments for the constructor they are become `undefined` and assigned to the props. You could use a default parameter value `null` to declare that these parameters are optional and handle them accordingly in the constructur:

```js
class Rectangle {
  height = 10;
  width = 10;
  constructor(width = null, height = null) {
    width === null || (this.width = width);
    height === null || (this.height = height);
  }
}

const rec = new Rectangle();

console.log(rec);
```

Of course you can write it this way:

```js
class Rectangle {
  constructor(width = 10, height = 10) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
  }
}

const rec = new Rectangle();

console.log(rec);
```

You could ask what's the difference. Well, they are documented: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields

A general one example:

> By declaring a public field, you can ensure the field is always present, and the class definition is more self-documenting.

A specific one example:

> Because class fields are added using the [[DefineOwnProperty]] semantic (which is essentially Object.defineProperty()), field declarations in derived classes do not invoke setters in the base class. This behavior differs from using this.field = … in the constructor.

```js
class Shape{
  #width = 10;
  get width(){
    return this.#width;
  }
  set width(val){
    console.log('setting width');
    this.#width = val;
  }
}

class Rectangle extends Shape{
  width = 10;
}

class Rectangle2 extends Shape{
  constructor(width = 10){
    super();
    this.width = width;
  }
}

const rc = new Rectangle();
console.log(rc);
const rc2 = new Rectangle2();
console.log(rc2);
```

One subtle difference is performance also. Consider the default props as an object literal, and it should perform faster than assigning props in a constructor:

```
` Chrome/123
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                    n=10       |      n=100       |     n=1000     |     n=10000     
default props   ■ 1.00x x1b 341 | ■ 1.00x x10m 390 | ■ 1.00x x1m 52 | ■ 1.00x x10k 407
constructor       1.02x x1b 348 |   1.13x x10m 441 |   1.04x x1m 54 |   1.12x x10k 456
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

In Firefox the difference is opposite and extreme for some reasons:

```
` Firefox/124
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>                     n=10       |      n=100       |      n=1000       |      n=10000     
constructor     ■ 1.00x x10m 323 | ■ 1.00x x10m 739 | ■ 1.00x x100k 133 | ■ 1.00x x10k  262
default props     1.06x x10m 342 |   1.57x  x1m 116 |  15.79x  x10k 210 |  67.48x  x1k 1768
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
const $chunk = Array.from({length: 10}, () => Math.random().toString().slice(2, 8));
const $input = [...$chunk];

const genWithout = new Function('', `

  return class{
    ${ $input.map(prop => `prop${prop} = ${Math.random()}`).join(';') }
  }

`);

const genWith = new Function('', `

  return class{
    constructor(){
    ${$input.map(prop => `this.prop${prop} = ${Math.random()}`).join(';')}
    }
  }

`);

// @benchmark default props
const c = genWithout();
// @run
new c;

// @benchmark constructor
const d = genWith();
//@run
new d;


/*@skip*/ fetch('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js').then(r => r.text().then(eval));
```